# jetty-maven-plugin :stop > The parameters 'stopKey', 'stopPort' are missing or invalid

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, jetty, zk

I create and run simple project with following link address:

[Create and Run Your First ZK Application with Eclipse and Maven](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Quick_Start/Create_and_Run_Your_First_ZK_Application_with_Eclipse_and_Maven).

But When I build... I have below error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:7.6.8.v20121106:stop
>   (default-cli) on project asd: The parameters 'stopKey', 'stopPort' for
>   goal org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:7.6.8.v20121106:stop are
>   missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

Comment: link to zkoss.org is invalid. and [Jetty 7.x is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the settings of pom.xml with the following.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.8.v20121106</version>
    <configuration>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
            <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
        </webAppConfig>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project is using an older version of the jetty plugin. Update it to a version where `stopKey` and `stopPort` are optional by changing the the version tag value to:

```
<version>9.4.3.v20170317</version>
```

Full instructions here on configuring the maven jetty plugin are here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

Comment: It asks for even `9.4.8.v20171121`

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue as you, decided to replace the Jetty Server with Tomcat to get over this issue. In your pom.xml use the following.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
            <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
        </webAppConfig>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also when doing a 'Run As' from Eclipse, change Goals from previously described *jetty:stop jetty:run* TO *tomcat7:shutdown tomcat7:run*